# C# Puzzle within a puzzle, can't figure it out

Tags: c#, function, for-loop, puzzle

[image: This is the whole puzzle]

I need help with this puzzle of C#: Its a fill in the blanks game and the answers can be one of the following to the 7 spaces

**Blanks look like this _ and are highlighted & there are 7 of them**

The next part of the puzzle is 
What C# function can i call to replace the for loop and insert to satisfy ‘result == ?’ in the code below:

```
    var answer = "Please help me with this puzzle please"; 

    var words = new[] { "Please", "help", "me", "with", "this", "puzzle", "please" }; 

    var result = ?

    if ( result == answer )
    Console.WriteLine(“Correct!”);
```

Im guessing for this you will need somekind of linq query which will just fit in, but how ?

I'm personally mind blown since im not a fan of C#

Comment: Mike, at least write this down with proper indentation and make sure that you've got all the brackets right.

Comment: Everything ive double checked is right im not missing anything unless you can spot something in particular

Comment: Ive changed it and uploaded the image i have of the puzzle rather than writing it myself since im a starter on stackflow and im a student im not very good with stackflow and indenting code, sorry guys but i can still use all your help

Comment: We are not here to solve your homework Micheal. I suggest you write out this in a console app and step through it. If you get stuck with your code then raise a question. This is like your not trying.

Comment: Trust me i tried but i couldnt get far i got some right and after trying multiple times i thought id ask everyone else i cant really give half answers that will confuse everyone because i basically got only as far as 3 blanks and research on the internet wasn't really helping me

Comment: For the second part use string.Join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Basically just try out a few things, some other things are pretty logical (e.g. the `while(wordCount < 4)` due to the `wordCount` incrementing). Other things are just modulo arithmetic stuff which make the challenge a little bit harder. (Like `x % 1` is always `true`).

```
using System;

class Programm
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var answer = "Please help me with this puzzle please"; 
        var words = new[] { "Please", "help", "me", "with", "this", "puzzle", "please" };

        var result = "";
        var wordCount = 0;

        for (var iCount = 12; iCount > 0; iCount--)
        {
            while (wordCount < 4) //less than because word count get's incremented
            {
                if (iCount % 1 == 0)
                {
                    result += words[wordCount]; 
                    result += " ";
                    wordCount++;
                }

                if ((iCount * 6) == 24)
                {
                    result += words[wordCount]; 
                    result += " ";
                    wordCount++;
                }
                iCount--;
            }

            if (iCount % 3 != 1)
                continue;

            result += words[wordCount]; 

            if (wordCount != 6)
                result += " ";

            wordCount += 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);

        if ( result == answer )
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("FAIL!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would i use some kind of linq query to solve the last part of the question, that is what i can figure out through research to replace the for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the last part ot the question: use `string.Join`

```
    var answer = "Please help me with this puzzle please";

    var words = new[] { "Please", "help", "me", "with", "this", "puzzle", "please" };

    var result = string.Join(" ", words);

    if (result == answer)
        Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
```

Comment: Why wont it be a linq query?

Comment: Because this is "one simple C# function". In fact this is the simplest you can do to achieve the goal. A LINQ query would be more complex.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help i really do appreciate it